# GridView and icon mess while using "if (convertView == null)"

Tags: android, gridview, layout-inflater

I'm newbie in this area, so pls be patient :)

I'm using some LayoutInflater to set GridView with icon + text below. When I usit as below, everything goes fine. But when I remove comment mark "//" everything messess up. Icons are presented in wrong order and they even double in few places.

```
    View v;
//    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        tv.setText(kraj[position]);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mniejszy, mniejszy));
//    } else {
    //    v = (View) convertView;
//    }
    return v;
```

This is the tutorial I got part of the code from:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you set the image **only** when `convertView` is `null`(this will happen for example when the `GridView` is first shown on the screen), and as the `GridView` is scrolled(`convertView` will not be null) it will recycle row views so you'll end up with old rows which you didn't update with the new images/text. Your code should be like this:

```
View v;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);            
    } else {
       v = (View) convertView;
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
    tv.setText(kraj[position]);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
    iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mniejszy, mniejszy));
    return v;
```

Comment: Ok, so why is the "if" for? If it works fine without checking if convertView==0?

Comment: The `if` is a performance improvement, since if the View is already initialized, why reinflate it? You might not notice it on small lists, but on large lists not being wasteful helps a lot.

Comment: It makes sense! Thx for your help. If i gain some more reputation, I'll vote you Up :)

Answer (score 1):

What you experience is probably due to the fact `recycled view` has data that you previously assigned.

Please review below code for a direction.

```
View v;
if(convertView == null) {
  LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
} else {
 v = (View) convertView; 
}

// now override whatever `recycled view` has

     TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        tv.setText(kraj[position]);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mniejszy, mniejszy));

return v;
```

Comment: This is exacttly what was wrong! Thx!
I can't vote you up, cause i'm under 15 reputation, but thanx a lot!